# jquery hover multi elements of same class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with the 12 months of the year (jan to dec)

I then have some of the months grouped together, ie: jan to apr = group1, mar to jun = group2

So all I wanna do is change the background colour of all the items with the same group name.

```
$('.group1').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
});

$('.group2').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q49Rd/1/

UPDATE, I went with this solution - tx for ur assistance:

```
<script>";
for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
echo "$('.group$i').hover(function() {
    $('.group$i').addClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
}, function () {
    $('.group$i').removeClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
});";
}
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: we in 2012 use `list` for this kind of work. please avoid tables

Comment: and your answer is dont use `this` just specify the classname to change class name for all element of same group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this makes a difference but on the jquery documentation, the '.hover' function takes both a "handlerIn" and a "handlerOut" function.

You might try the following:

```
$('.group1').hover(function() {
    $('.group1').addClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
}, function() {
     $('.group1').removeClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
});

$('.group2').hover(function() {
    $('.group2').addClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
}, function () {
    $('.group2').removeClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
});
```

Not sure if this will make a difference or not. You may be able to specify only one function and get away with it. This will change the background color when one of the items is hovered over and then remove the coloring when you move off of the item.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `this` with the group class name, you can also use `toggleClass` method.

```
$('.group1').hover(function() {
    $('.group1').toggleClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
});

$('.group2').hover(function() {
    $('.group2').toggleClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5cAfR/

Please note that you haven't loaded jQuery in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `this` use the class name insted to make change in all

```
$(this).addClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
```

**Should BE**

```
$(".group1").addClass('tbl_navGroupHover');
```